# Erros em um Multiway MergeSort-Externo em C

Tags: c

implementei um código em C de uma ordenação Multiway MergeSort Externa que lê os valores em um arquivo.txt, passa esses valores para os arquivos de entrada e fica migrando dos arquivos de entrada para os de saída, até ordenar. A parte de passar para os arquivos de entrada está ok, funciona. O problema está na parte de migrar entre em um arquivo para outro, especificamente com um `fscanf()`.

Eu tenho uma struct que contém um array de FILEs e uma funçao apenas para abrir cada um dos arquivos de entrada.txt formados e armazená-los no array de FILEs, e deixá-los abertos. Em outra funçao, eu leio um valor em cada um desses arquivos ja abertos (que estão dentro do array de FILEs na struct), através de um `fscanf()`.

Eu preciso que os arquivos estejam abertos pois a função para ler deles é chamada várias vezes e eu preciso continuar de onde foi feita a última leitura.

Infelizmente, o que acontece é que o programa simplesmente trava no momento em que chega no `fscanf()`.

Posso enviar o código para testar.

---

Respectivamente: a struct com o array de FILES(o restantes é um array de int para uso futuro). a função para abrir os arquivos e deixá-los abertos e a função que lê o conteúdo de cada arquivo já aberto.

```
typedef struct TArquivos{
    FILE **arquivos;
    int *restantes;
}TArquivos;
```

Criando a struct e inicializando seus arrays (Detalhe, m é uma variável, no caso, a quantidade de arquivos que serão lidos

```
TArquivos *manipula = (TArquivos*)malloc(sizeof(TArquivos));
manipula->arquivos = (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*)*m);
manipula->restantes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
```

A função para abrir os arquivos e deixá-los abertos. Ars_input é um array de string com o nome dos arquivos armazenados.

```
void abrearquivos(TArquivos *manipul, char **arqs_Input, int m){
    int co;
    for(co = 0;co<m;co++){
        manipul->arquivos[co] = fopen(arqs_Input[co], "r");
    }
}
```

A função que lê o conteúdo de cada arquivo já aberto.

```
void inserePrimeiros(TNo *Arv, TArquivos *arqmanip, int cont){
    int inser;
    FILE *ar;
    for(inser = 0; inser<cont; inser++){
        arqmanip->restantes[inser]--;
        int varTemp;
        ar = arqmanip->arquivos[inser];
        fscanf(ar, "%ld", &varTemp);
        TValores *valor = (TValores*)malloc(sizeof(TValores));
        valor->arquivoCorresp = inser;
        valor->n = varTemp;
        insereArvore(valor, Arv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim por favor adicione o código ao corpo da pergunta, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Tens aqui um erro

```
        int varTemp;                     // tipo de variavel
        ar = arqmanip->arquivos[inser];
        fscanf(ar, "%ld", &varTemp);     // e especificacao de scanf
                                         // incompativeis
```

A variavel `verTemp` tem tipo `int`; nao podes usar o especificador `"%ld"` com o endereco dessa variavel. Tens de usar `"%d"` ou alterar o tipo de `varTemp` para `long`.